# Contar o número de caracteres de um valor dentro de uma coluna de um DataGridView [C#]

Tags: c#, mysql

Como conta o número de caracteres de um valor dentro de uma coluna de uma `DataGridView`?

O objetivo é adicionar 0,02€ por cada letra na coluna `mensagem` e depois colocar o total numa `Label`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqu]

Comment: Se estamos no [pt.so], por que não pergunta em português mesmo?

Answer (score 1):

A resposta é relativamente fácil com `LINQ`:

```
var linhas = myDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(r => Convert.ToString(r.Cells["mensagem"].Value));
double somaLinhas = linhas.Sum(r => r.Length * 0.02);

lblSoma.Text = string.Format(@"{0:#,##0.00}", somaLinhas);
```

O nome da coluna `mensagem` terá de ser alterado caso não seja esse o nome efetivo, assim como a `Label` `lblSoma` e a `myDataGridView`.